# Biber exits with "WARN - No data sources defined!"

Tags: bibtex, xetex, errors, biber

I am trying to use biber with XeTeX. Whenever I try to run biber against my `.bcf` file (generated via biblatex with the biber backend properly stated), I have the following output:

> ```
> INFO - This is Biber 2.2
> INFO - Logfile is 'tese.blg'
> INFO - Reading 'tese.bcf'
> WARN - No data sources defined!
> ```

I have already tried cleaning the PAR cache, as per advice found googling and researching here at this forum, but nothing changed after that (`rm -rf $(biber --cache)`). My biber/biblatex versions are compatible and up to date.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: do you have an \addbibresource in your document?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, I don't. Should I?

Comment: Sure. How else should biblatex know where your bib-entries are?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, I did not realize that (new to biblatex/biber)... I replaced my `\bibliography` with `\addbibresource`, but the error remains when I call biber. Thanks anyway!

Comment: There's a difference with the `\bibliography` command: you should add the `.bib` extension.

Comment: @Bernard I did that, sorry for not mentioning it before.

Comment: \addbibresource must be in the preamble.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Aha. That solved the problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment